# Using spring cloud gateway for routing grpc traffic

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, grpc, netflix-zuul

Is it supported?
Any good examples or documentation available on this subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently supported. There is an open issue to investigate support.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+grpc

Comment: Trying to build a cloud gateway to route requests from gRPC client to REST. Able to get the response from REST and send to the client. But client always reports Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: HTTP status code 200 invalid content-type: application/json

Comment: This feature now exists https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/08/spring-cloud-gateway-and-grpc (article by my coworker)